# Point-free: confused about where to put parenthesis

Tags: syntax, ocaml, pointfree

```
let list_to_string = (String.concat "") (List.map (String.make 1));;
```

This is wrong, but how do I make it understand that the argument is still to be supplied? The argument is expected to be of type `char list`, I.e. the first function that needs to be applied to it is the `(List.map (String.make 1))`, and then pass it to `String.concat ""`. I think I've tried all combinations of parenthesis I could think of... no joy so far.

Help?

I also figured I could do it like this:

```
let ($) f g x = f (g x);;
let list_to_string = (String.concat "") $ (List.map (String.make 1));;
```

But just wanted to make sure there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real (and always perplexing) problem is that OCaml doesn't have a built-in function composition operator. So it's not so good out of the box for pointfree coding. If you really want to get fancy with it, you also need `flip`, which inverts the order of the arguments of a two-argument function.

```
let flip f a b = f b a
```

At any rate, I don't see any problem with your solution once you've defined function composition as `$`. You can leave out some of the parentheses:

```
# let lts = String.concat "" $ List.map (String.make 1);;
val lts : char list -> string = <fun>
```

As to efficiency, I assume this is more of a puzzle than a practical bit of code. Otherwise you should use the functions that Edwin suggests.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that partial application helps here, just write out the function parameter:

```
let list_to_string x = String.concat "" (List.map (String.make 1) x)
```

This isn't very efficient though, it would be better to create just one string and fill it with characters.

If you use Batteries then see [Batstring.of_list](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc/BatString.html#VALof_list), and if you use Core then see [String.of_char_list](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core/String.html#VALof_char_list)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely just define a function composition operator in OCaml. It just can't be dot because that's already an operator in OCaml.

```
(* I just made up this symbol *)
let (^.^) f g x = f (g x)
let list_to_string = String.concat "" ^.^ List.map (String.make 1);;
```