# Compose total and partial functions

Tags: ocaml, composition

I can't wrap my head around where should I put parenthesis to get it working:

```
let read_lines filename =
  let channel = open_in filename in
  Std.input_list channel;;

let print_lines filename =
  List.map print_string ((^) "\n") (read_lines filename);;
```

^ This is the closes I've got so far. If my terminology is vague: `((^) "\n")` is what I call partial function (well, because it doesn't handle all of its arguments). `print_string` I call total function because... well, it handles all of its arguments.

Obviously, what I would like to happen is that:

1. `List.map` applies first `((^) "\n")` to the element of the list.
2. `List.map` applies `print_string` to the result of #1.

How? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Point-free: confused about where to put parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120081/point-free-confused-about-where-to-put-parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like that?

```
# let ($) f g = fun x -> f(g x);;
val ( $ ) : ('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b = <fun>
# let f = print_string $ (fun s -> s^"\n");;
val f : string -> unit = <fun>
# List.iter f ["a";"b";"c";"d"];;
a
b
c
d
- : unit = ()
# let g = string_of_int $ ((+)1) $ int_of_string;;
val g : string -> string = <fun>
# g "1";;
- : string = "2"
```

Your code didn't work because missing parenthesis:

```
List.map print_string ((^) "\n") xs
```

is parsed as

```
(List.map print_string ((^) "\n")) xs
```

when you expected

```
List.map (print_string ((^) "\n")) xs
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things: `List.map` is probably not what you want, since it will produce a list (of unit values) rather than just iterating. `((^) "\n")` is probably also not what you want, as it *prepends* a newline, the `"\n"` being the first argument. (This is not a section as in Haskell, but a straightforward partial application.)

Here's a reasonable solution that is close to what (I think) you want:

```
let print_lines filename =
  List.iter (fun str -> print_string (str ^ "\n")) (read_lines filename)
```

But I would rather write

```
let print_lines filename =
  List.iter (Printf.printf "%s\n") (read_lines filename)
```

Which is both clearer and more efficient.